# C string input output

Tags: c, scanf, c-strings

This is the code I am executing:

```
scanf("%s",expr);
i=0,j=0;
while(expr[i]!='+')
{
    l[j++]=expr[i++];
}
    j=0;

while(expr[i]!='=')
{
    r[j++]=expr[i++];
}
    j=0;

while(expr[i]!='\0')
{
    s[j++]=expr[i++];
}
printf("%s %d %s %d %s %d",l,strlen(l),r,strlen(r),s,strlen(s));
```

I cannot understand why this is not showing proper output.
For e.g. in case of `1+1=2`
Output should have been `1 1 +1 2 =2 2`
But what i am getting is `1 2symbols 3 +1 2 =2 3symbols 5`

Comment: You need to properly terminate all strings in C.

Comment: Yeah Got it. Thanks, sometimes small things mess up entire code;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `\0` at the end of each string.

```
scanf("%s",expr);
i=0,j=0;

while(expr[i]!='+')
{
    l[j++]=expr[i++];
}
l[j]='\0'; //here
j=0;

while(expr[i]!='=')
{
    r[j++]=expr[i++];
}
r[j]='\0'; //here
j=0;

while(expr[i]!='\0')
{
    s[j++]=expr[i++];
}
s[j]='\0'; //and here

printf("%s %d %s %d %s %d",l,strlen(l),r,strlen(r),s,strlen(s));
```